# Prolog Lists, Add 1 to tail of the list

Tags: list, math, prolog

I'm trying to add either 1 or 2 to numbers in a list in SWI-Prolog.

I've managed to add 1 or 2 to the head of the list however I'm having difficulties adding onto each element on the tail of the list. I don't want to add 1 or 2 to EVERY element at the same time just at separate times. I.e. If my input is 
    add([2,3,4], X).

I would like the possibilities of X to be the following:
    `X = [3,3,4]`
    `X = [4,3,4]`
    `X = [2,4,4]`
    `X = [2,5,4]`
    `X = [2,3,5]`
    `X = [2,3,6]`

My code at present is:

```
add([],[]).
add([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
                    is(H2,+(H1,1)), T1=T2;
                    is(H2,+(H1,2)), T1=T2.
```

Obviously this only adds 1 or 2 onto the head of the list and not the tail. Therefore does anyone know how I may go about adding 1 or 2 onto the elements in the tail of my list?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using prefix notation for infix operations?

Comment: To be honest I'm new to prolog and that way just sort of made sense. I'm sure my way of coding isn't the optimal way to do so haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometime more verbose can be clearer:

```
add([],[]).
add([H1|T],[H2|T]) :-
 H2 is H1+1.
add([H1|T],[H2|T]) :-
 H2 is H1+2.
add([H|T1],[H|T2]) :-
 add(T1,T2).
```

now alternatives are listed out, the last one just handles - recursively - the remaining elements

Anyway, your code is just missing a line:

```
add([],[]).
add([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
 is(H2,+(H1,1)), T1=T2;
 is(H2,+(H1,2)), T1=T2;
 H1=H2, add(T1,T2).
```

After comment, here is how to subtract and keep only positive values:

```
add([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
 H2 is H1-1, H2 > 0, T1=T2;
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I were to change the add to subtraction I sometimes get negative numbers which I don't want, in addition to not wanting 0's in my list. Therefore I think that by deleting the element if it's -1, or 0 is the easiest solution to this problem but again I'm not 100% sure how to implement this :/

Comment: Thanks for your edit once again! :) Whilst this helps it isn't exactly what I was trying to achieve but that's because I didn't explain properly. So if I have a query: `add([1,2,3], X).` and were to subtract by 1 using this code I would get `X = [0,2,3]`, `X = [1,1,3]`, and `X = [1,2,2]`. However although this is correct I would like the 0 to be removed from the list completely. i.e. for the first result it would be `X = [2,3]`. I've found help on how to remove nth element but not any for removing a specific character or number

Answer (score 1):

First define a predicate `addX/3` that will add X to one of the members of the first list:

```
addX([], [],_).     % base case
addX([H|T], [H1 | T], X) :- H1 is H + X.   % add to first element
addX([H|T], [H | T1], X) :- addX(T, T1, X). % or retain the first element and add to some element in the tail
```

Than using it define your `add` predicate as `addX` with `X=1` or `X=2`:

```
add(L, R) :- addX(L, R, 1).
add(L, R) :- addX(L, R, 2).
```

Testing:

```
?- add([2,3,4], X).
X = [3, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 4, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 5] ;
X = [2, 3, 4] ;
X = [4, 3, 4] ;
X = [2, 5, 4] ;
X = [2, 3, 6] ;
X = [2, 3, 4].
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I were to change the add to subtraction I sometimes get negative numbers which I don't want, in addition to not wanting 0's in my list. Therefore I think that by deleting the element if it's -1, or 0 is the easiest solution to this problem but again I'm not 100% sure how to implement this :/